# Parsing command and arguments with a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a small Ruby CLI which should take a command and some arguments.

For example, I should be able to do:

```
attribute value
```

or:

```
attribute (value1, value2)
```

or:

```
attribute (value1, value2) and attribute2 (value3, value4)
```

or any combination.

I'd like to get back something like:

```
[['attribute', ['value1', 'value2']], ['attribute2', ['value3', 'value4']]]
```

I came up with this regex

```
(\b[a-z_]{1}\w+)\s{1}\((.*?)\)
```

which gets me partially there, in that it matches the attribute and both the values (as a whole, like `[['attribute', 'value1, value2']]`, but it doesn't match something like `attribute value`.

Comment: Not sure you can extract an undeterminate number of words from your string with a regex. You may have to parse it with something else. What about splitting your string on `and` separator, then extracting `attribute` and `(values)` as you already do, and finally recovering distinct `values` by splitting on commas?

Comment: I thought about that. Like, I can definitely do some splitting and regex and get to where I want to be, but I was curious if there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: The regex for this kind of request is going to be monstrously complicated for a "regex noob" so I would suggest sticking with ruby's fancy split methods. It gets the job done and will be much more readable later if you ever come back to edit it a few months from now.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how extensive of input you require, but something like [this](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) might do the trick. It works similarly to the shell getOpts.